# Podcast 67 community bulletin link is 404

Tags: bug, blog, 404-not-found, community-bulletin

The latest blog post link (a podcast) which has been added to the Community Bulletin is a 404.

The link from the Community Bulletin is the following, which is a 404:

- http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/08/stack-exchange-podcast-67-the-firehose-of-nerd-dom/

The actual link should be:

- http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/08/stack-exchange-podcast-67-anil-dash-and-the-firehose-of-nerd-dom/

Comment: This is now completely fixed; not sure this bug report really needs to stay around...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minutes later and the link has now been fixed, and the link anchor text changed to the new correct title, although this has not propagated throughout the entirety of the network yet (caching).